# Mulesoft Anypoint studio will not install the AMQP connector

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, anypoint-studio

I want to use Mulesoft Anypoint studio to listen to some queues in rabbitMQ. But the latest version of Anypoint will not let me install the AMQP connector from the Anypoint Exchange suggested by several documentations. It will tell me `Cannot complete the request see the error log for details`. First of all I can not find the error log of the Anypoint Studio. But there is a hidden .log file in the workdirectory, but it also said `See the error log for details`.

Does anybody have a solution for this, or know what is wrong with the AMQP connector on the Anypoint Exchange?

When I want to install another connector like the MongoDB Connector, everything went ok.

Comment: What version of Studio are you using?

Answer (score 4):

You can install it as follows:

- go to Help -> Install new software
- select Anypoint Connectors Update Site
- select Community -> Mule AMQP Transport

Comment: This worked. Although it's concerning that the OP's issue still exists as of today.

Comment: @JustinSkiles indeed, one of the many pleasures of working with Anypoint Studio :/

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the Connector's update site following the steps below:

1. Go to **Preferences**
2. Select **Install/Update** --> **Available Software Sites**
3. Select the **Connectors Update Site** and clic option "Reload".

[image]